# How do I add an array INDEX function nested inside of a GETPIVOTDATA function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a workbook with two spreadsheets. Sheet 1 has a pivot table, Sheet 2 has the comparable data and a GETPIVOTDATA formula. I am having trouble getting my formula to work. I think it is because I have a nested INDEX/MATCH array formula (which works find on its own), but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is what I have so far:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[M].[U A]",'Sheet 1'!$A$10,"[A].[P]","[A].[P].[R T 1].&["&'Sheet 2'!F$1&"]","[S].[S N]","[S].[S N].&["&INDEX('Sheet 1'!A:A,MATCH('Sheet 2'!A12,LEFT('Sheet 1'!A:A,FIND("_", 'Sheet 1'!A:A&"_")-1),0))&"]")
```

I am getting a #REF error. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: @pnuts Evaluate is having trouble at the "FIND("_", 'Sheet 1'!A:A&"_")-1),0)" portion, as I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing an argument in you `INDEX` bit. i assume one for column number.

Comment: I thought about that, but this is working on its own: '{=INDEX('IS SBU (2)'!A:A,MATCH(A13,LEFT('IS SBU (2)'!A:A,FIND("_", 'IS SBU (2)'!A:A&"_")-1),0))}'. That's what confuses me, and I'm assuming that I can't have the array inside of the GETPIVOTDATA formula. Any suggestions?

Comment: Put array formula in one column and `GETPIVOTDATA` in a column next to it reading from the first one

Comment: I was trying to do it without adding a helper column. Is this possible (without using VBA)?

Comment: Never tried anything as complicated as adding array formula as an argument into `GETPIVOTDATA ` so don't know, sorry. Maybe someone else has better idea.